# Modularize CSS Flip Function

Tags: html, css

I have created the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gzskc0ao/1/) in which are two boxes that flip once they are clicked, allowing different content to display on each side. 
The metro-style layout will eventually look [this](http://file.mrbool.com/mrbool/articles/JoelRodrigues/MetroMenuStyle/MenuMetroHTML2.jpg), as per a clever [tutorial by Mr Bool](http://mrbool.com/creating-a-metro-style-menu-in-html-and-css/26266).

**Issue:**
1) Following the same principle as the large flip boxes visible from my code, I would like to make a second smaller box with the dimensions `110px` by `110px` (instead of the large box shown) and place this on the same line as the first (not below).
2) The parts of the CSS that make it flip should be modular so that I can add a `flip-container-small` class to the second box, hence retaining the effect just with a smaller box.

```css
@font-face { font-family: Century; src: url('GOTHIC.ttf'); }

body{
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(51,51,51);
    color: #fff;
    padding:20px;
    /*width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;*/
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.amarelo {
    background:#DAA520;
}

.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
        -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
         -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
             -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
            -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
                user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently supported by Chrome and Opera */
            cursor: default; /* Cursor normal instead of highlighter (i.e: I ) */
}

.all {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}

.row {
    width:auto;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    height:auto;
    display:table;
}

/* Flip Box Rules Below */

/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000px;
}
.flip-container-small {
    height:110px;   
    width:110px;
}
/* flip the pane when hovered */
.flip-container.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
/* Common pane settings */
.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width:225px;
    height:110px;
    border-radius: 2.5px;
}
/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}
/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    /* Aligning Content in box centered */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center;
    text-align: center;
}
/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    /* for firefox 31 */
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<body class="noselect">
    <h1>Alignment - Testing (click box to flip)</h1>

    <div class="all">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- First Box Start -->
            <div class="flip-container" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                <div class="flipper">
                    <div class="front amarelo">
                        <!-- front content -->
                        <h2 id="24hrClock">13:22</h2>
                        <h4 id="longDate">Monday 01 January 2000</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back amarelo">
                        <!-- back content -->
                        <h2 id="12hrClock">1:22 PM</h2>
                        <h4 id="shortDate">01/01/00</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- First Box End -->

            <!-- Second Box Start -->
            <div class="flip-container" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                <div class="flipper">
                    <div class="front amarelo">
                        <!-- front content -->
                        <h2 id="24hrClock"></h2>
                        <h4 id="longDate">Resize this to 110px x 110px, place to right side of above</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back amarelo">
                        <!-- back content -->
                        <h2 id="12hrClock"></h2>
                        <h4 id="shortDate"></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Second Box End -->
            <p>I would like to have a second flip box with the smaller size of 110px x 110px right next to the first (not below).<br> NOTE: I want to reuse existing code from the large container, just with new dimensions, as the flipping principle is the same.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

**Desired Outcome:** [image]

I hope I have provided all the information required, if you need additional info, just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many frustrating hours, I was finally able to get the outcome I was after (minus the responsiveness of the layout - which I didn't ask for in this thread).

My solution and responsive layout question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45936146/responsive-html-tiles-fill-browser-window) for anyone who is interested.