# Responsive HTML Tiles - Fill Browser Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

My recently created [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gq5qb7yu/) contains a basic layout with containers that display content on both sides (once clicked on, they flip over). When I resize the browser window, I would like everything to be larger or smaller (essentially responsive) without compromising the spaces in between or the general layout of the page.

**Question:** How would I scale my content to the **hight** of browser window while maintaining the aspect-ratio of the tiles?

After hours of searching, I am still no closer to making the content responsive and would like to ask for some help. Surely, there is a way.

```css
@font-face { font-family: Century; src: url('GOTHIC.ttf'); }
 
body {
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(51,51,51);
    color: #fff;
    padding:20px;
    min-width:800px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
}
h6 {
    font-size: 15px;
}

.amarelo {
    background:#DAA520;
}
 
.vermelho {
    background:#CD0000;  
}
 
.azul {
    background:#4682B4;
}
 
.verde {
    background-color: #2E8B57;
}

.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
        -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
        -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
            -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
            -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
                user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently supported by Chrome and Opera */
                cursor: default; /* Cursor normal instead of highlighter (i.e: I ) */
}

.all-rows {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.row {
    width:auto;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    height:auto;
    display:table;
}

/* Remove padding from last box in row / last row in all-rows */
.flip-container:last-child, .flip-container-small:last-child {
    padding-right: 0px;
}
.row:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.row:first-child {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

/* Flip Box Rules Below */

/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
    width:225px;
    height:110px;
}
.flip-container-small {
    width:110px;
    height:110px; 
}
.flip-container, .flip-container-small {
    perspective: 1000px;
    float: left; /* Added to place on same line */
    padding-right: 5px;
}
/* flip the pane when hovered */
.flip-container.hover .flipper, .flip-container-small.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
 transition: 1.5s;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}
/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    border-radius: 2.5px;
    /* Aligning Content in box centered */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center;
    text-align: center;
}
/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg); /* for firefox 31 */
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<body class="noselect">
        <h1>Responsive - Testing Interface</h1>

        <div class="all-rows">
            <!-- First Row Start -->
            <div class="row">
                <!-- First Box Start -->
                <div class="flip-container" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front amarelo">
                            <!-- front content -->
                            <h2 id="24hrClock">1</h2>
                            <h4 id="longDate">2</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back amarelo">
                            <!-- back content -->
                            <h2 id="12hrClock">3</h2>
                            <h4 id="shortDate">4</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- First Box End -->

                <!-- Second Box Start -->
                <div class="flip-container-small" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front amarelo">
                            <!-- front content -->
                            <h2 id="24hrClock">1</h2>
                            <h4 id="longDate">2</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back amarelo">
                            <!-- back content -->
                            <h2 id="12hrClock">3</h2>
                            <h4 id="shortDate">4</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Second Box End -->

                <!-- Third Box Start -->
                <div class="flip-container-small" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front verde">
                            <!-- front content -->
                            <h2 id="24hrClock">1</h2>
                            <h4 id="longDate">2</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back verde">
                            <!-- back content -->
                            <h2 id="12hrClock">3</h2>
                            <h4 id="shortDate">4</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Third Box End -->

                <!-- Fourth Box Start -->
                <div class="flip-container-small" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front verde">
                            <!-- front content -->
                            <h2 id="24hrClock">1</h2>
                            <h4 id="longDate">2</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back verde">
                            <!-- back content -->
                            <h2 id="12hrClock">3</h2>
                            <h4 id="shortDate">4</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Fourth Box End -->

                <!-- Fifth Box Start -->
                <div class="flip-container-small" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front verde">
                            <!-- front content -->
                            <h2 id="24hrClock">1</h2>
                            <h4 id="longDate">2</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back verde">
                            <!-- back content -->
                            <h2 id="12hrClock">3</h2>
                            <h4 id="shortDate">4</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Fifth Box End -->
    
                <!-- Sixth Box Start -->
                <div class="flip-container-small" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front verde">
                            <!-- front content -->
                            <h2 id="24hrClock">1</h2>
                            <h4 id="longDate">2</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back verde">
                            <!-- back content -->
                            <h2 id="12hrClock">3</h2>
                            <h4 id="shortDate">4</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Sixth Box End -->
            </div>
            <!-- First Row End -->

            <!-- Second Row Start -->
            <div class="row">  
                <!-- First Box Start -->
                <div class="flip-container-small" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front amarelo">
                            <!-- front content -->
                            <h2 id="24hrClock">1</h2>
                            <h4 id="longDate">2</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back amarelo">
                            <!-- back content -->
                            <h2 id="12hrClock">3</h2>
                            <h4 id="shortDate">4</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- First Box End -->
    
                <!-- Second Box Start -->
                <div class="flip-container-small" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front amarelo">
                            <!-- front content -->
                            <h2 id="24hrClock">1</h2>
                            <h4 id="longDate">2</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back amarelo">
                            <!-- back content -->
                            <h2 id="12hrClock">3</h2>
                            <h4 id="shortDate">4</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Second Box End -->

                <!-- Third Box Start -->
                <div class="flip-container-small" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front amarelo">
                            <!-- front content -->
                            <h2 id="24hrClock">1</h2>
                            <h4 id="longDate">2</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back amarelo">
                            <!-- back content -->
                            <h2 id="12hrClock">3</h2>
                            <h4 id="shortDate">4</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Third Box End -->

                <!-- Fourth Box Start -->
                <div class="flip-container-small" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front amarelo">
                            <!-- front content -->
                            <h2 id="24hrClock">1</h2>
                            <h4 id="longDate">2</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back amarelo">
                            <!-- back content -->
                            <h2 id="12hrClock">3</h2>
                            <h4 id="shortDate">4</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Fourth Box End -->

                <!-- Fifth Box Start -->
                <div class="flip-container" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front amarelo">
                            <!-- front content -->
                            <h2 id="24hrClock">1</h2>
                            <h4 id="longDate">2</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back amarelo">
                            <!-- back content -->
                            <h2 id="12hrClock">3</h2>
                            <h4 id="shortDate">4</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Fifth Box End -->
    
                <!-- Sixth Box Start -->
                <div class="flip-container-small" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front amarelo">
                            <!-- front content -->
                            <h2 id="24hrClock">1</h2>
                            <h4 id="longDate">2</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back amarelo">
                            <!-- back content -->
                            <h2 id="12hrClock">3</h2>
                            <h4 id="shortDate">4</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Sixth Box End -->
            </div>
            <!-- Second Row End -->

            <!-- Third Row Start -->
            <div class="row">   
                <!-- First Box Start -->
                <div class="flip-container-small" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front amarelo">
                            <!-- front content -->
                            <h2 id="24hrClock">1</h2>
                            <h4 id="longDate">2</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back amarelo">
                            <!-- back content -->
                            <h2 id="12hrClock">3</h2>
                            <h4 id="shortDate">4</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- First Box End -->
    
                <!-- Second Box Start -->
                <div class="flip-container-small" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front amarelo">
                            <!-- front content -->
                            <h2 id="24hrClock">1</h2>
                            <h4 id="longDate">2</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back amarelo">
                            <!-- back content -->
                            <h2 id="12hrClock">3</h2>
                            <h4 id="shortDate">4</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Second Box End -->

                <!-- Third Box Start -->
                <div class="flip-container-small" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front amarelo">
                            <!-- front content -->
                            <h2 id="24hrClock">1</h2>
                            <h4 id="longDate">2</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back amarelo">
                            <!-- back content -->
                            <h2 id="12hrClock">3</h2>
                            <h4 id="shortDate">4</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Third Box End -->

                <!-- Fourth Box Start -->
                <div class="flip-container" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front amarelo">
                            <!-- front content -->
                            <h2 id="24hrClock">1</h2>
                            <h4 id="longDate">2</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back amarelo">
                            <!-- back content -->
                            <h2 id="12hrClock">3</h2>
                            <h4 id="shortDate">4</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Fourth Box End -->

                <!-- Fifth Box Start -->
                <div class="flip-container-small" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front amarelo">
                            <!-- front content -->
                            <h2 id="24hrClock">1</h2>
                            <h4 id="longDate">2</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back amarelo">
                            <!-- back content -->
                            <h2 id="12hrClock">3</h2>
                            <h4 id="shortDate">4</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Fifth Box End -->
    
                <!-- Sixth Box Start -->
                <div class="flip-container-small" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front amarelo">
                            <!-- front content -->
                            <h2 id="24hrClock">1</h2>
                            <h4 id="longDate">2</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back amarelo">
                            <!-- back content -->
                            <h2 id="12hrClock">3</h2>
                            <h4 id="shortDate">4</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Sixth Box End -->
            </div>
            <!-- Third Row End -->
        </div>
        <p>I would like to have a second flip box with the smaller size of 110px x 110px right next to the first (not below).<br> NOTE: I want to reuse existing code from the large container, just with new dimensions, as the flipping principle is the same.</p>
    </body>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `height:100vh;`?

Comment: Try in style height:30%  like this not 100px

Comment: @artgb No luck for either of the above-mentioned suggestions. Any thoughts?